# How to solve $-3\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}u\delta (u)du$

Tags: dirac-delta

I working through the question in the link and i am stuck on something:

[How to solve integration with Dirac Delta function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408959/how-to-solve-integration-with-dirac-delta-function)

How does one solve the equation:  $\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}(-\frac{1}{2}-3u)\delta (u)du$

My solution:

$\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}(-\frac{1}{2}-3u)\delta (u)du =$

$\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}(-\frac{1}{2})\delta (u)du-\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}(-3u)\delta (u)du=$

$-\frac{1}{2}\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}\delta (u)du-3\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}u\delta (u)du=$

$-1/2-3\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}u\delta (u)du $

I dont't know how to solve this equation:
$-3\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}u\delta (u)du$

Edit:

Would anyone mind explaining why: $\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}u\delta (u)du=0$. Or in wider sence why $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x\delta (x)dx=0$

Answer (score 2):

The [delta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) has the property that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)\delta(u-a)du=f(a)$$
or $$\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(u)\delta(u-a)du=f(a)$$

for $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta(u-a)=0$ for $u\neq a$. In your case $f(u)=-\frac{1}{2}-3u$ and $a=0$ (which lies in the interval $[\frac{-5}{6},\frac{11}{5}]$), thus we have $$\int_{\frac{11}{6}}^{-\frac{5}{6}}f(u)\delta(u)du=-\int_{-\frac{5}{6}}^{\frac{11}{5}}f(u)\delta(u)du$$
$$=-f(0)=-(-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition (of the Dirac delta function),
$$\delta(u) = 0 \:\: \text{for}\:\: u\ne 0\implies -\int_{11/6}^{5/6}\left(3u+\frac{1}{2}\right)\delta(u) \:du=0$$
since the range of integration does not contain $0$.

---

EDIT $1$
I just took a look at the link in the post and realized that there could be a bunch of typos in the question. Henceforth, I shall assume that this is what the OP actually wants:

$$\int_{-5/6}^{11/6}\left(\frac{1}{2}-3u\right)\delta(u)\:du$$
We have that
$$\boxed{\:\int_c^d f(t)\delta(t-a)\:dt=f(a),\:\:\:\:\:\text{ if $a\in(c,d)$}\:\:}\tag{1}$$
Observe that $0$ is contained in the range of integration. Therefore,
$$\int_{-5/6}^{11/6}\left(\frac{1}{2}-3u\right)\delta(u)\:du=\frac{1}{2}-3(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

---

EDIT $2$
Observe that
$$\int_{11/6}^{-5/6}u\delta(u)\:du=\int_{-5/6}^{11/6}u\delta(u)\:du $$
After an application of $(1)$, we arrive at the desired answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry the the integral was supposed to -5/6 not 5/6

Comment: Would you mind explaining why: $\int^{-5/6}_{11/6}u\delta (u)du=0$. Or in wider sence why $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x\delta (x)dx=0$

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please take a look now.